# Dual mappings - from U to V and from V to W

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, dual-maps

Can someone explain to me with the help of a diagram/illustration the subject of dual mapping
I'm getting confused.
I know that $W$ maps using a linear function $f$, vectors to scalars.
Can I write that $R$ is the $W*$?
and why
$S^*(f) = fS$
After all, $S^*$ is a transition from $W^*$ to $V^*$. If I run a function $f$ on it, how do I get $R$?
I'm lost ...
I would appreciate a verbal explanation along with an illustration
Thank you!!! :)
[image]

Comment: R is in the dual space of W so $R \in W^*$. $W^*$ is the set of all linear mappings from W to the field it is over, so in this case the set of all linear maps $f:W \longrightarrow R$.

Comment: Hi, thanks
So why S*(f) = fS ?  can you add a diagram that explain the connection between f and the dual space ?